# Does Apache Sling have symbolic links for nodes?

Tags: sling

I'd like to normalize my repository. I've got a bunch of identical nodes - identical properties and identical child nodes with their identical properties. I'd like to have just one node that defines the properties and children and have the rest just reference it, thereby eliminating a bunch of redundant nodes.

Is there some property that I can add to a node to make it a duplicate of another without having to actually copy it, like a Unix symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the x-ref component?  It creates a node that points to the original node & renders the original node instead.